# Forward PDF printer through RDP

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, remote-desktop, port-forwarding, pdfcreator

I'm using a Windows 10 machine (x64) which connect through RDP to a Windows 7 machine (x86). Printer forwarding is enabled and all phsysical printers are forwarded. Just my pdfforge PDFCreator Printer is not appearing.

I also installied the PDF printer software on the Win7 machine to make sure that the driver is installed 'cause I couldn't find the x86 driver itself.

Any idea to fix this?

Comment: This likely has to do with the fact one installation is 32-bit and the other is 64-bit.

Comment: I also thought thats the problem but after installing that whole PDFCreator software on the x86 machine it didn't solved the issue.

Comment: It wouldn't have since the printer being shared is from a 64-bit installation.

Comment: Would an explicit export and import of the driver solve that problem?
https://superuser.com/questions/1196061/how-to-export-installed-device-driver-on-windows-7-for-later-use

Comment: You can't install 64-bit drivers on a 32-bit installation of Windows.

Comment: Correct, but I can also add a x86 driver through offering the printer as a network share, or not? Otherwise, is there any solution to solve this issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118331/discussion-between-manukilled-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 0):

you can turn on logging for the PDFCreator from the “PDF Print Monitor” (Printer->Logging)
and for the pdfcmon.dll by adding the following entry to your registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\pdfcmon name : Logging, value :1 ( logfile created in%Windir%\Temp_pdfcmonLog.txt)
maybe these logs will help to track down the problem.

https://forums.pdfforge.org/t/pdf-creator-on-printer-server/10006